# How can I create a JQuery accordion navigation that stays open?

Tags: jquery, navigation, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to create an accordion navigation menu that stays open when I click a certain page. Unfortunately after trying solutions that I have found online I still can't get it to open.

This is my JQuery :

```
$(function() {
    var icons = {
    header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
    activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };

    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    header: "h3",
    navigation: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    icons: icons
    });
    $( "#toggle" ).button().click(function() {
    if ( $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" ) ) {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", null );
    } else {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", icons );
    }
    });
});
```

And this is my menu :

```
<div id="accordion" style="float:left;">
  <h3>Datamarts & Logs</h3>
  <div>
    <a href="index.php"><div class="left_menu_button">Registered instances</div></a>
    <a href="add_instance.php"><div class="left_menu_button">Add instance</div></a>
    <a href="databases_info.php"><div class="left_menu_button">Databases info & logs</div></a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Administration</h3>
  <div>
    <a href="operations_history.php"><div class="left_menu_button">Operations history</div></a>
    <a href="users.php"><div class="left_menu_button">Users</div></a>
  </div>
  <h3>Tools</h3>
  <div>
    <a href="links.php"><div class="left_menu_button"><span>Links</span></div></a>
        <a href="projects.php"><div class="left_menu_button"><span>Projects</span></div></a>       
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to add #id to the h3 or to the anchor at the end of the link, but it still did not work. I do however have a function that compares each anchor to the url but don't know how to use it with the menu.

I would really appreciate some help on this subject.

Thank you !

Comment: You can add the id of which ever accordion tab is currently selected to the query string when a menu button is pressed. Then on page load, if the query string exists, selected that tab again.

Comment: I've tried the following and it still doesnt work :    $('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', 4);
    $("#accordion").accordion("activate",4);

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have one extra

```
</div>
```

Please remove it and try again. Usually this kind of minor problems cause accordion not to work properly or not work at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In fact when I copied the code I accidently copied an extra div. The accordion menu works fine. The problem is that when changing pages it doesn't stay open.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out...
I have to use $('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', 3); 
Apparently 3 is the number of the H3 not the anchor, so the 4 I was using did not correspond to anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html5, you can store the accordion index in the `localStorage["key"]` before going to a new page. The `localStorage["key"]` works as a persistent storage.

```
localStorage["last_opened_index"] = accordionIndex;
```

then on the next page:

```
var acc_index = = localStorage["last_opened_index"] !== undefined ? localStorage["last_opened_index"] : localStorage["last_opened_index"] = 0;

$('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', acc_index);
```

If you have a better way than this, please comment how, I'll add vote if you have to compensate for it :D